# cant update user attributes in installData

Tags: magento, module, magento2

I create custom module.
After i try to add custom attribute in InstallData.php
I remove my module from setup_module to run install data however i don`t see any results nor error.
I try run setup:upgrade c:c c:f

I want to add custom attribute to user information. To update that information after user is register account. Also I want after to have ability to change it from admin area and from front settings. But for now i cant make work to see it in admin.
Should I add any additional code to run this ?

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\RewardPoints\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /* Create customer attribute for front-end builder*/
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_telephone', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'My telephone',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'is_used_in_grid' => 1,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => 1,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => 1,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => 1,
            'position' => 1000,
            'default' => 0,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_telephone')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);

        $attribute->save();


    }
}
```

Comment: Is the module enabled (set to 1) in app/etc/config.php?

Comment: It was. Problem was i had not module:enable and than setup:upgrade fix problem

Answer (score 0):

In the article [Magento 2: How to make customer attribute?](http://blog.sashas.org/magento-2-make-customer-attribute.html) describe it step by step.
Customer attributes can be used in different forms, this example will show customer attribute at the admin customer edit page.  You can also use also other forms. For example:
“used_in_forms” =>  `[‘adminhtml_customer_address’, ‘customer_address_edit’, ‘customer_register_address’]`

Comment: It was correct . I have to module:enable and than s:up. I was doing only s:up